# How to do user authentication with Amazon athena?

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2, user-controls, amazon-athena

How to access amazon athena? 
Is it possible to do user authentication with amazon athena?
How we can restrict the user's to do query over s3 using athena ?

Answer (score 0):

For Authentication and Authorization in Amazon Web Services, you are going to use [Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/).  Unlike Relational Database Management Systems (RDMSs) including those managed via (RDS), Athena does not come with its own access controls.

To set up permissions for Athena see the following, [AWS Documentation » Amazon Athena » User Guide » Security » Access Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/access.html).

Answer (score -1):

Kindly go through the aws athena docs https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/athena/, It depends upon your usage. If you are having requirement of daily analysis of data then you can create data pipelines and query the data. Kindly use aws provided JDBC/ODBC driver to link to Athena.

Comment: I went through the link, but still unable to find for integration of aws athena through EC2 instance. 
How to do changes in Apache Hue for JDBC driver os Athena?

Comment: I referred the link you've shared. I wanted to run queries through data pipeline, but not sure how to create them. I've installed JDBC drivers on EC2 instance but still didn't get the way to connect Athena.

Comment: 1. Create IAM and get access keys to access the  Athena

2. Use AthenaJDBC41 jar files to access the Athena

3. Use Java examples provided in Docs

4. Use AthenaJDBC41 jar to run the class

Comment: Thanks  user5811898,
I have made some changes in jdbc driver then accessed Athena.
It works !!

Comment: You can provide those details here, as it help other developers who get this issue